# Repeat and increase Pandas's column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to Pandas so this may sound stupid. My dataframe looks like the one below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9HYv.png)

The goal is to check the field 'D' and create D rows with same ID but increment the 'Time' by 5 for each row.
For example if the ID = 3, Time = 0 and D = 5 then I would like to have further 5 rows following the original row with the same ID but the time increases by 5 for each row. so the Time field will be 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 while the other fields in the rows remain the same.

Is this possible in pandas? I have tried the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(probeTTableTups, columns=['ID','Time','D'])
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.D)].reset_index(drop=True)
df2['Time'] += 5
print(df2)
```

I tried to repeat rows D times and increase the Time field by 5 but it just created same value for the Time while i need to have the incremental numbers in Time column.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per duplicated index values and multiple `5`:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.D)]
df2['Time'] = df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount() * 5
```

If need also add `Times`:

```
df2['Time'] = df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount() * 5 + df2['Time']
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot buddy!! You literally saved my day! if you don't mind i ask a bit more.. what does level= 0 means? In the picture you can see I currently have only one record. Would the code still work the same way if I have more records? for example if I have 2 original rows now. the second being ID: 4 Time: 700.0 D: 5. Would it still produce 7 rows of first record and then 5 rows of second record?

Comment: @1010100010010101010101010 - Exactly it is for reason if multiple values per `D`, so grouping for repeated index values and processing.